Avoid Java debugger extension in VS code directly using classes from other .java files?
I just want my .java file to use classes defined in this file or have access to .class files in the same folder. However, the Java debugger can run a program by using classes in other .java files, even in other folders, which really confuses me.
What I learned in the textbook is that a .java file can use a class in a .class file in the same folder or use import or package statements to introduce other classes.
I completed the exercises in the textbook without using the Java extension and just installed the Java debugger when I started learning the algorithm part.
so I met a problem: when copying a class from a .java file, pasting it into a new one, and modifying it, this new class can't be used in the new file when I launch this file by using the run and debug function. I looked up their troubleshooting doc, it says "If there are multiple classes with the same name in the current workspace, the debugger uses the one inside the project specified by projectName.". So even though I define this class in the new file, the original one is invoked. How to modify it so that it can just use classes the way I expected?  Meanwhile, The new file can be executed successfully when I use the terminal command linejava fileName.java.
For example,
I have a file: OldFile.java file under /Users/Liam/Documents/Java/src/chapter1
public class OldFile {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    CustomClass cc = new CustomClass(1, 2); // 2 arguments
  }
}
class CustomClass {
  private int num1;
  private int num2;
  public CustomClass(){
    this(0,0);
  }
  public CustomClass(int num1, int num2){
    this.num1 = num1;
    this.num2 = num2;
  }
}

and another file: NewFile.java file under /Users/Liam/Documents/Java/src/chapter2
public class NewFile {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    CustomClass cc = new CustomClass(1); //1 argument
  }
}
class CustomClass {
  private int num1;
  public CustomClass(){
    this(0);
  }
  public CustomClass(int num1){
    this.num1 = num1;
  }
}

When I use the run and debug function to launch NewFile.java provided by Java debugger, it will report an error, saying that the constructor with one parameter is not defined. But it works fine with java NewFile.java.
And the funny thing is if you rename NewFile.java into OldFile.java and change the class name in the file as well, no matter how you modify this file, it will read the OldFile.java under chapter2. This is very counterintuitive.
one possible way I think how Java debugger can do things like this is it compile all my .java files in the same project into a shared package.
My expectation is that when using the Java debugger to run and debug a program, it won't use directly classes in other files without my instructions. It should use or introduce classes the way defined in the Java language explicitly
I have read their https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug, and tried several things:

set force build before Launch false. it doesn't work.

change the classpath or module path options in the launch.json, it doesn't work.
"classPaths": ["${workspaceFolder}/Welcome.java"], //result: can't find the main class
"classPaths": ["$Runtime"], //result: doesn't change anything, no such constructor.
"modulePaths": ["$Runtime"], //result: Cannot resolve the modulepaths/classpaths automatically, please specify the value in the launch.json.
"modulePaths": ["${workspaceFolder}/Welcome.java"], //result:  java.lang.module.FindException: Module format not recognized




are you using gradle, maven, or .project?

Hi, thank you for replying. No, I don't use Maven. I installed Maven when I started learning JavaFX in the textbook to create a JavaFX application, but later I learned how to run a JavaFX application with a non-modular project with IDE, so I gave up Maven. I created a Maven project under my workspace folder, but later I deleted it.
Generally, I just create a new file, save it as a .java file,  and start coding.

yes, it is related to the project, I analyzed the launch command in the terminal and found out how to solve it by editing launch.json and setting.json. Finally, I got rid of this sting on my finger.

I have solved my problem. it is about Java project management. Need to define the source code path and classpath or preferred library path clearly, or errors will occur.
My confusion was caused by the Java project manager extension. I am not familiar with how it manages the project, source code, and dependencies, etc.
I think novices like me should read this before using Project Manager for Java. But I believe it is hard to notice because this extension will be installed automatically and take effect when you install the Java Extension.
The run function in VScode highly relates to the Project Manager for Java (and Java Language support by Red Hat?).
first, make sure that the path of your source file is included in the project's source path. You can check and modify it in the classpath configuration. If not, even though your .java file is right in front of you, the terminal will report can't find the main class.
Second:
By default, VS Code will reference all JAR files in the workspace's lib directory using the glob pattern lib/**/*.jar. This is why even though your .java files are in different folders, their classes can still be used in other files. You can open the setting.json, and delete it or just comment on it, like this:
You need to clean the workspace to make this configuration effective.
enter image description here
"java.project.referencedLibraries": [
    //"library/**/*.jar",
    "/home/username/lib/foo.jar"
]

Third, you may need to provide the relative path of the file when you read one in your code even though this file is in the same folder as your .java file.
Anyway, the way the Project Manager for Java extension manages files is different from my previous experience with Explorer and what I learned from the textbook. I think a tutorial about Project Manager for Java and Language Support for Java is necessary for me.
You can extract useful information from the terminal when using the run function. In my case, it is:
 /usr/bin/env /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java @/var/folders/md/z863cl2n1w96cynyz6pb6_sm0000gn/T/cp_cinb17o2fklp89b2r9my34wo3.argfile Exercise_20_02 

I found this file in Explorer, copied the content, and asked ChatGPT to explain it. Then I found that it contained instructions that require JVM to run the .java file in a specified folder(The output path configured in Project Manager), not the one I am working on, and the libraries it should include.
Something like:
--module-path /Users/Liam/Documents/Java/JavaFXLib/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages -cp "/Users/Liam/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/2eb5daea473a49fdecb7d969670b7544/redhat.java/jdt_ws/Java_c5f66059/bin:/Users/Liam/Documents/Java/JavaFXLib/lib/javafx.fxml.jar:/Users/Liam/Documents/Java/JavaFXLib/lib/javafx.base.jar:/Users/Liam/Documents/Java/JavaFXLib/lib/javafx.controls.jar:/Users/Liam/Documents/Java/JavaFXLib/lib/javafx.web.jar:/Users/Liam/Documents/Java/JavaFXLib/lib/javafx-swt.jar:/Users/Liam/Documents/Java/JavaFXLib/lib/javafx.graphics.jar:/Users/Liam/Documents/Java/JavaFXLib/lib/javafx.swing.jar:/Users/Liam/Documents/Java/JavaFXLib/lib/javafx.media.jar"


can you please show concretely what you did with path and classpath? (sorry to keep pointing you to this, but again, see [answer])
